# Running Spark2.3 on Kubernetes with remote dependency on S3

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running `spark-submit` to run on Kubernetes (Spark 2.3). My problem is that the `InitContainer` does not download my jar file if it's specified as an s3a:// path but does work if I put my jar on an HTTP server and use http://. The spark driver fails, of course, because it can't find my Class (and the jar file in fact is not in the image).

I have tried two approaches:

1. specifying the s3a path to jar as the  argument to spark-submit and
2. using `--jars` to specify the jar file's location on s3a, but both fail in the same way.

edit: also, using local:///home/myuser/app.jar does not work with the same symptoms.

On a failed run (dependency on s3a), I logged into the container and found the directory /var/spark-data/spark-jars/ to be empty. The init-container logs don't indicate any type of error.

Questions:

1. What is the correct way to specify remote dependencies on S3A?
2. Is S3A not supported yet?  Only http(s)?
3. Any suggestions on how to further debug the InitContainer to determine why the download doesn't happen?

Comment: I am sorry but the S3 you refer is AWS S3 or the Hadoop's S3A?

Comment: Oh and another question - does your container/machine on which container is running has access to S3/

Comment: I am referring to S3A, not AWS's S3.


I *think* my container has access. Specifically, the container successfully accesses s3a so it could be an issue with the InitContainer only, though I didn't think so because I'm using the same underlying image for all containers.


Extra clarification: my Spark job reads/writes from S3A and this succeeds as long as I use http for the remote dependency, so this verifies that the S3A access is working, but there could easily be something specific to the InitContainer I don't understand that makes it not work with S3A.